# Removing artifact in Plot[1-(1-x)^Floor[2/x],{x,0,1/20}]

Tags: plotting, precision-and-accuracy

The input

```
Plot[1-(1-x)^Floor[2/x],{x,0,1/20}]
```

yields

[image: plot with artifact]

where the white space we see below the curve near $x=0.01$ is an artifact. How can we fix this simply? `WorkingPrecision -> 999` does not help, the issue is the way $x$ is sampled.

Comment: Try the option `PlotPoints -> 10^4`.

Comment: @Roman: if you don't make this an answer, I will!

Comment: Please make it an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Roman gave the solution:

```
Plot[1-(1-x)^Floor[2/x],{x,0,1/20}, PlotPoints -> 10^4]
```

yields
[image: no artifact]

Comment: As a general rule it is more efficient to increase both `MaxRecursion` and `PlotPoints` rather than depend solely on `PlotPoints`